# RouteBuilder with multiple routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using a route builder in my Camel Context like this:

```
<bean class="mypackage.MyRouteBuilder" id="MyRouteBuilder"/>
<camelContext id="mypackage.camelcontext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="MyRouteBuilder"/>
</camelContext>
```

I have implemented a RouteBuilder like this:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{ 
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("direct:MyRouteBuilder")
        .log("Route Builder: ${body}");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to implement more routes in the same route builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can implement a lot of routes in the same route builder like this, I advise you to use routeId for identify the route in the logs and use the .end() to finish the block

```
    from("direct:route1")
     .routeId("route1")
     .log("Route Builder: ${body}")
     .end();
   from("direct:route2")
    .routeId("route2")
    .log("Route Builder: ${body}")
    .end();
  from("direct:route3")
   .routeId("route3")
   .log("Route Builder: ${body}")
   .end();
```